# External Login without using identity asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to create an external login scheme for facebook, google and linkedin without using identity framework. I have an api that stores all users and do some authentication stuffs. Right now I'm kind of lost on how to get the information from the external login.

I'm issuing a challenge like this.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
{
    //Issue a challenge to external login middleware to trigger sign in process
    return new ChallengeResult(provider);
}
```

This works well, it redirects me to either google, facebook or linkedinn authentication.

Now on this part:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
{
    //Extract info from externa; login

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

All I want is to get the information that was provided by the external login.

I have tried what I found from my research,

```
 var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(provider);
 if (result?.Succeeded != true)
 {
     return Redirect("/");
 }
 var externalUser = result.Principal;
 var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();
```

First of all I I'm not sure if a simple `?provider=Google` on my callback string will pass the provider name I specify so it can be used to check the sign in scheme. I guess this is incorrect. Secondly, I tried hard coding `await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("Google")` and when it reach this code, the debug stops. I'm not sure why.

I've seen the generated code when creating a project with single authentication.

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

Sadly, I'm won't be able to use identity since I don't have a user store and my application will be consuming an API.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a solution? Can't find any documentation or examples on how you can do this without asp.net identity... :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to create a custom cookie handler. I myself had problems with:

> No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is configured to handle sign in for
>   the scheme: Bearer

I had to add a cookie handler that will temporarily store the outcome of the external authentication, e.g. the claims that got sent by the external provider. This is necessary, since there are typically a couple of redirects involved until you are done with the external authentication process.

**Startup**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
})
.AddCookie("YourCustomScheme")
.AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.SignInScheme = "YourCustomScheme";
    googleOptions.ClientId = "x";//Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "x";//Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    //googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/api/authentication/externalauthentication/signin-google";
});
```

The important part here is "YourCustomScheme".

Now it's time to retrieve the user information from the claims provided by the external authentication in the callback action.

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost(nameof(ExternalLogin))]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(ExternalLoginModel model)
{
    if (model == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = _authenticationAppSettings.External.RedirectUri };

    return Challenge(properties, model.Provider);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback))]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    //Here we can retrieve the claims
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("YourCustomScheme");

    return null;
}
```

Voilà! We now have some user information to work with!

[image]

**Helpful link**

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html

Comment: Hi, I have followed what what you've done and I did it yesterday but a while after I was always getting an error: "Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest;Headers: Cache-Control: no-store". If I debug it goes to a method like the one ljpv14 has shown in the main post, ExternalLogin. That's correct. But after I return new ChallengeResult("Facebook"); it just goes in a loop. Why does that happen?

Comment: If I put the line "var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync("YourCustomScheme");" in the method, it gets the info on the second go, but still continues on a loop. And I don't know why.

Comment: Do you have both actions, ExternalLogIn and ExternalLoginCallback? You should return challenge in the first and retrieve the data in the second, (with httpcontext.authenticateasync). Sorry I have not experienced these problems, let's see what ljpv14 says and if he has the same problems, maybe he can provide some code then.
Also this link might give you a better understanding of how it works, it did for me. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin_external_providers.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I was missing the AuthenticationProperties object with the RedirectUri. It made a huge difference. With that said, you might want to include that in your answer, for future refernce to whom might be in trouble. And since it doesn't hurt, the link you provided too.

Comment: I haven't tried with other providers but I guess it must be all the same, at least the ones that are configured. Other providers might be a bit different but no too far from the tree.

Comment: Great. I'd choose this as the accepted answer, but I'm not the OP. :)

Comment: do you have problems with maintaining cookies? Whenever I login, be it through the app account or the external provider account, if I restart the browser (tried on Chrome and Firefox) the cookies are cleared...

Comment: I only use the cookie for the initial load, inside the callback. When i have all the information i need i create a jwt token and send it back to the client. I dont know how persistent the cookie is, maybe theres options for that when you create it in the startup? Otherwise you might need to create your own cookie from the callback cookie. Hope i got your question right now

Comment: Ok, I got it. Since you mentioned the persistence, I remembered to have seen such a property. So, you have to add the "IsPersistent = true" to the AuthenticationProperties. And then you can set the options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0); in the cookie (if you really want to keep a cookie. This will maintain it for 30 days. You can choose any time you want. If you don't add this to the cookie options it will use the default, which is 14 days.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while. I resulted to use a lower framework version in order to get it done since my client's been bugging me with deadlines and doesn't mind using lower versions. But for helping out a fellow developer as a substitute for me as the OP I will grant your answer as accepted. Cheers mate!

Answer (score -3):

I too had this issue and see if the below code works for you.
I wanted to extract the full name after Google/FB authentication.

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

TempData["fullname"] = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
```